# How to find the number of HTML elements with a name that starts with a certain string in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure if the topic describes my problem very well but I am creating some HTML elements (textboxes) on the fly with jQuery and I never know how many I will create (it loops through a database). I then want to get all the elements in the code behind and perform some actions (insert them into another database).

I know I can use

```
string n = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["hiddenField0"]).ToString();
```

To get the first textbox but what if Idon't know how many textboxes I have created and want them all? Their name starts with hiddenField plus an incrementing number.

Is there a way to loop through all elements that has a name that starts with a certain string?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var dictionary = Request.Form.Keys
     .Cast<string>()
     .Where(x => x.StartsWith("abc"))
     .ToDictionary(x => x, x => Request.Form[x]);
```

Returns a dictionary containing the keys/values for all form elements that start with "abc".

**Update:** The poor OP is using .Net 2.0.  So here is the old-school answer:

```
Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string key in request.Form.Keys)
{
    if (key.StartsWith("abc"))
         keys[key] = request.Form[key];
}
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it. :) I was proposing to use `BaseGetAllKeys` method (as `Request.Form` is a `NameValueCollection`). Saves the cast, as it returns a `string[]`.

Comment: @RPM1984, I see `BaseGetAllKeys` declared as `protected`, no?

Comment: Hi, I get 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) when tryint to do this

Comment: @Morgan - what version of .NET are you running?

Comment: @Morgan, do you have `using System.Linq;`?   Also, @RPM1984 asks a good question, as `Cast` (and the rest of LINQ) is only available in .NET3.5 and above.

Comment: It's a 2.0 asp.net web application so no linq, can't run 3.5 or 4 in this project, forgot to mention that, sorry

Comment: @Morgan, you have my most sincere pity.  ;)  But I updated the answer for .Net 2.0.